# How to transfer commission to specific customer from our account on shopify store. Need details

Tags: e-commerce, shopify, customization

I would like to transfer a commission to a specific customer from our account on shopify store, but I'm not sure how?
What code should I embed?  Where and how?

My question is: How to send 30% of subtotal of order to a specific customer, with the tag "agent" after checkout.  This means 30% of the subtotal amount will be automatically transfered from my N26 account to the user's paypal or bank account.

Answer (score 0):

I made an App for this about 8 years ago. Called Transparent Kitty. You can assign whatever % you want to the vendor (A user with an email is then assigned this vendor)...

So whenever you sell anything, you can keep track of what % of the sale they get.

Comment: It's pretty good but i need an app that can add it's customers with account on store as sale Agents ... let suppose a customer buy a product on my store and this customer is not consumer he is buying for a person. what we want to do we wish to send 30% at the same time of checkout.so that customer can see that earn commission instantly on spot?

Comment: Roll your own e-commerce then.. that pattern is not something you can do with Shopify without headaches.